# Does ZipInputStream in JAVA refers to data in compressed data?

Tags: java

I am working on small module where I want to read the data from ZIP file using streaming. ZIP size is large and I want to keep `ZipInputStream` reference in memory for longer duration.

So I have two basic questions:

1. Does `ZipInputStream` holds whole ZIP data in memory?
2. Is data referred by `ZipInputStream` in compressed format?

Comment: I do not understand your second question.

Comment: Which data do you mean by "reffered by". There are 2 different sorts of data: the input data (compressed) and the output data (uncompressed).

Comment: Regarding point 2, When I started to read the data using "ZipInputStream " then as per my understanding data gets streamed in memory. Then this streamed data is in compressed or un-compressed state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZipInputStream do not work with `.zip` files. You should use `ZipFile` instead.

ZipInputStream doesn't hold all content in memory. It process data on the fly.

Comment: I am using streaming, Zip is on Server. And I managed to read the inner files of Zip using ZipInputStream.  I want to hold ZipInpuStream reference in memory. My only concern is that files data referred by ZipInpuStream is in  compressed or non-compressed format?

Comment: Zip stream do not hold any data at all. It decompress it when you need them. You should worry about underlying stream.

Answer (score 1):

`ZipInputStream` is a stream that unzips the source data it's "connected" to. If you have a zipped file, you can read it with a `FileInputStream` and get the compressed bytes. If you attach a `ZipInputStream` to that `FileInputStream` you can then read the uncompressed bytes.

As with all streaming, not all of the data is kept in memory at the same time, but rather as you keep reading the bytes will be fetched and uncompressed.

Comment: Actually I don't want to keep the zip copy on local hard disk. So I can't use "FileInputStream".  So if read the whole ZIP file using ZipInputStream then does it means that I have all data in uncompressed format loaded in memory?

Comment: I was using `FileInputStream` as an example. It can be a `SocketInputStream`, a `ByteArrayInputStream` or any other `InputStream`.